# macOS partially blurring text in mac apps on external display

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, text

This issue is distinct from [Turn off blurring on Mac Book Pro with Retina display](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/75882/turn-off-blurring-on-mac-book-pro-with-retina-display), because part of the text is crisp, part is blurry.

After upgrading to Big Sur, I've noticed an odd blur effect happening in text rendering when text appears:

1. On my external display(s), Dell UltraSharp (via displayport, dvi, hdmi)
2. In Apple programs like messages, mail
3. Both light and dark mode

Is there a way to disable blur effects/text-gradients/whatever is causing this?

[image: text-render-diff]

Comment: Entirely possible my eyes are going bad and the above images are identical, let me know if that's the case

Comment: My elderly eyes see the blur. Are these screen-caps or actual photos of the screen?

Comment: These are screenshots